# How can i display my date in 3 ways?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display my date in 3 ways using the int Display Date, but everytime i call for the date, the output is "The date is 0".
I'm trying to display all 3 of them seperately. I tried to call them through the parameter and set the parameter at 3 but only 0 displayed.

```
using System;

public class Date
{
    private int month;
    private int date;
    private int year;
    private int parameter;
    private int p;
    private int DisplayDate;

    public Date(int p)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }

    public int getmonth()
    {
        return month;
    }
    public void setmonth(int m)
    {
        month = m;
    }
    public void setmonth(string m)
    {
        month = int.Parse(m);
    }
    public int getdate()
    {
        return date;
    }
    public void setdate(int d)
    {
        date = d;
    }
    public int getyear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    public void setyear(int y)
    {
        year = y;
    }
    public int getparameter()
    {
        return parameter;
    }
    public void setparameter(int p)
    {
        parameter = p;
        if (p <= 3)
        {
            if (p == 1)
            {
                setmonth("1");
                setdate(22);
                setyear(2015);
            }
            else if (p == 2)
            {
                setyear(2015);
                setmonth("2");
                setdate(20);
            }
            else if (p == 3)
            {
                setmonth("March");
                setdate(10);
                setyear(2015);
            }
        }

    }

}

class DateTest
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Date D = new Date (3);
        Console.WriteLine("The Date is {0}", D.getparameter());
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't call `setparameter()` then `getparameter()` returns `0` which is the default value of the `int parameter` field.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the original `System.DateTime` is a `struct` (value-type) not a `class` (reference type).

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a very good time to a) learn .NET naming conventions; b) learn about properties, as a more idiomatic approach than your get/set methods; c) tell us what you expected to see, given that you're only printing the result of calling `D.getparameter()` once.

Comment: @haim770: I'm not sure how that's relevant, as `DateTime` isn't mentioned here.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I know. But if you were to write your own `Date` type, i'm sure you'll use a `struct`.

Comment: @haim770: Possibly, but I think there are rather bigger issues to worry about to start with. Hopefully the OP is just learning about C#, not *actually* creating their own date/time API. (Who would do that, after all? ;)

Comment: Do you really need your own `Date` type? Can't you just use `System.DateTime`?

Comment: Yeah, i needed to input the dates manually.

Comment: My problem is, i know how to display 1 date, but can't get the other 2 to display at the same time.

Comment: as an aside: your `setmonth("March")` will fail. An `int.Parse` of "March" will give an exception, not return "3".

Answer (score 0):

but you do not set parameter in your code :)

```
public Date(int p)
{
    this.p = p;//you set p, not parameter in your constructor
}
```

you should call the method setParameter() if you want to set it.

Comment: If i set the parameter to 3, then how will i be able to get the output to display the other 2, after i run the code?

Comment: actually what is the purpose of class ? if you set your parameter 3, then you are not able to output the other if you do not change your code... or you could simply create new instance where you set the other dates

Comment: The purpose of this class is to display 3 dates in 3 different formats at the same time. I displayed 1, but can't get the other 2 to display also, without going back and changing the parameter.

Comment: mhh, you are right, so this is not the best design of this, but i think that you need to show 3 dates, so why do not you change your implementation design?

Comment: you should not call get parameter and wait that it returns 3 dates, because of its funcionality and the basic principle of OOP = high cohesion and single responsibility - the better way is to create 3 instances and each instance would have one date - could this be?

Comment: and you are not needed variable p in your class

Comment: Would this then allow me to display all of the dates at once?

Comment: actually not, only if you call it like this: Date d1= new Date(1);Date d2= new Date(2);Date d3= new Date(3); and now you call d1.getParameter, d2.getParameter, d3.getparameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the setparameter() method, that's why your getparameter() returns 0.
Try calling it in the constructor with p as parameter.

```
    public Date(int p)
{
    this.p = p;
    this.setparameter(p);
}
```

like this.